# For rails3, cedar stack or bamboo stack?

Tags: caching, heroku, asset-pipeline, rails-3.1, cedar

I need to create an application on heroku, But I am confused in selecting a better stack. For rail3.1 application, which heroku stack is better in terms of caching, speed and assets pipeline ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Heroku docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar):

> While Rails 3.1 can run on the Bamboo stack without the asset
>   pipeline, Rails 3.1 runs best on Heroku’s Cedar stack. For new users,
>   we recommend reading [our tutorial for creating a Rails 3.0 app on
>   Cedar](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) before proceeding further.

It seems the asset pipeline is only supported on the Cedar stack.